# Understanding a function containing the delta-function

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I have been given the problem to solve the Poisson equation:
$$\vec{\nabla}^2 u(\vec{r})=\rho(\vec{r}), \quad z>0$$
And the professor then writes that the inhomogeneity is thus given by:
$$\rho(\vec{r})=\delta(\vec{r}-\vec{a}),\quad \vec{a}=(0,0,a),\quad a\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$$
But... Does this not imply that $\rho(\vec{r})$ is infinite at every point along the $z$-axis for $z>0$ and zero everywhere else? Does anyone know how I am to interpret that equation?

Comment: No, it is only "infinite" at the point $\vec{a}$, in other words this is a point charge. What does the potential of point charge in free space look like? Did you have any boundary conditions for the plane $z=0$?

Comment: @LucasE You may want to refer the definition of the Dirac delta function https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function because your question is directly related to the function itself

Comment: Sure, but remember $r_0$ is a variable, not just a fixed point.

Comment: Can you tell me what part is no longer true?

Comment: The boundary condition changes everything! That integral is no longer true.

Comment: But if I integrate over the entire volume, wouldn't $\rho(\vec{r})=\delta(\vec{r}-\vec{a})$ return zero everywhere except when $\vec{r}={a}$? If that is the case, then why is the integral i wrote not correct?

Comment: Mathematically, it's because you forgot the fundamental theorem of calculus (or divergence theorem in this case), there is always a boundary (surface integral) term involved that we don't see usually because we assume that the integral over a boundary at infinity vanishes. Physically, the $z=0$ plane does not want to be an equipotential surface since equipotential surfaces of point charges are usually spheres. It takes energy to keep it an equipotential surface.

Comment: You posted this on the mathematics stack exchange, not on the physics site, so I will comment on the delta distribution. This is not a function. It does not take on the value "infinity" on $a$ and zero "elsewhere". If you want to rigorously understand the equation and understand how something like this can be the derivative of something else you would have to learn the basics of the theory of distributions. This is often viewed as unwieldy, which is why physicists don't talk about distributions and pretend that dirac delta is a function. But you did post this on math stack exchange.

Comment: Yes, I know it is not a true function. I am simply trying to solve my problem, without having to learn too much about things like theory of distributions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard image charge question. If have the condition that $u(z=0) = 0$, then we can use the existence and uniqueness property of solutions of the Poisson equation to avoid computing the integral.

We have a point charge located at $$\vec{a} = (0,0,a)$$ Now pretend we have another point charge of the opposite sign located at

$$\vec{a}' = (0,0,-a)$$

Of course this is silly, this point does not exist in our space. But if it did, notice that the electric potential on the $z=0$ plane would always be $0$. In other words, this is a different situation that agrees with ours on the upper half space $z > 0$. We can use existence and uniqueness to assert that the solution to our problem is the same as the solution to this problem.

Thus the electric potential everywhere ($z>0$) is given by

$$u(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{4\pi|\vec{r}-\vec{a}|} - \frac{1}{4\pi|\vec{r}-\vec{a}'|}$$

or

$$u(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{4\pi|\vec{r}-\vec{a}|} - \frac{1}{4\pi|\vec{r}+\vec{a}|}$$

since $\vec{a}$ points solely in the $z$ direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But i assume the full solution to $u(\vec{r})$ includes a surface integral, correct? I'm not asking you to show this, simply a yes/no answer would suffice.

Comment: @LucasE I'm not sure what you are asking. This is the full solution.

Comment: @LucasE yes that is right. In this case we have Dirichlet conditions so $f(S) = 0$.

Comment: Ahh, right. Thank you very much for your time.